# MVC4 : What entity represents table webpages_Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm trying to access webpages_Membership table (I'm using SimpleMembership) to retrieve the account ConfirmationToken.

How do I access this table from my model/controller/DAL?

The only thing I can think of is executing pure SQL from my code to get this value, but that's doesn't seem like it's the right thing to do, nor elegant.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, there's no direct way to retrieve the value using `WebSecurity` helper.

When you create a User and Account the method returns the confirmation token:

```
string confirmationToken = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("tester", "test123", requireConfirmationToken: true);
```

You then send this token (inside a link as a QueryString parameter for example) to the User's e-mail address. When the user clicks the link, your app must get/read this token and then you must call:

```
WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(userName, confirmationToken);
```

As you mentioned you can of course hit the db directly writing your own SQL or even add the `webpages_Membership` to an EntityFramewok EDMX model and query the table directly:

```
var confirmationToken = Database.Memberships.Single(m => m.UserId == userId).ConfirmationToken;
```

More on this:

[Using the confirmation feature for ASP.NET Web Pages security](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/AddComment.aspx?blogid=2267)

[Get Account Confirmation Token?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1733841.aspx/1?Get%20Account%20Confirmation%20Token%20)

Comment: Thanks Leniel.  What you described is my intention, but sometimes the user (for whatever reason) wants to have the confirmation email re-sent.  How would we implement a re-send function without using custom sql to retrieve the original confirmationToken?

Comment: In this case you can use the Database helper described here to retrieve the `confirmationToken` for the user: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/156/WebMatrix-Database-Helpers-for-IN-Clauses